# How does defining an explicit destructor for a C++ struct affect calling conventions?

Tags: c++, assembly, struct, calling-convention

A coworker poked me with this question, after noticing a curious behavior with C++ structs.

Take this trivial code:

```
struct S {
  int i;
#ifdef TEST
  ~S() {}
#endif
};

void foo (S s) {
  (void)s;
}

int main () {
  foo(S());
  return 0;
}
```

I have generated the assembly code once without the explicit destructor:

```
g++-4.7.2 destructor.cc -S -O0 -o destructor_no.s
```

and later including it:

```
g++-4.7.2 destructor.cc -DTEST -S -O0 -o destructor_yes.s
```

This is the code[1] for `main` in `destructor_no.s`:

```
main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    movl    $0, %eax
    movl    %eax, %edi
    call    _Z3foo1S   // call to foo()
    movl    $0, %eax
    popq    %rbp
    ret
```

While, instead, if the destructor is defined explicitly:

```
main:
    pushq   %rbp
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
    subq    $16, %rsp
    movl    $0, -16(%rbp)
    leaq    -16(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _Z3foo1S   // call to foo()
    leaq    -16(%rbp), %rax
    movq    %rax, %rdi
    call    _ZN1SD1Ev  // call to S::~S()
    movl    $0, %eax
    leave
    ret
```

Now, my assembly knowledge is a bit rusty, but it seems to me that:

1. in the first case, the struct is passed "by value". I.e., its memory content is copied into the `%edi` register, that, if I am not mistaken, is the first register used for argument passing in the `x86-64` ABI.
2. in the second case, instead, the struct is allocated on the stack, but the `foo()` function is called with a pointer in `%rdi`.

**Why is there such a difference?**

---

*Notes:*

- The same behavior is confirmed if using `gcc-4.6.3`, or `clang 3.1`.
- Of course, if optimizations are enabled, the call to function `foo()` is completely optimized away in any case.
- An interesting pattern emerges when adding more variables to the `struct`, if no destructor is explicly provided.

Up to 4 `int`s (= 16 bytes) are passed through the argument registers:

```
pushq   %rbp
movq    %rsp, %rbp
subq    $16, %rsp
movl    $0, -16(%rbp)
movl    $0, -12(%rbp)
movl    $0, -8(%rbp)
movl    $0, -4(%rbp)
movq    -16(%rbp), %rdx
movq    -8(%rbp), %rax
movq    %rdx, %rdi
movq    %rax, %rsi
call    _Z3foo1S
```

but as soon as I add a fifth `int` to the struct, the argument to the function, still passed "by value", is now on the stack:

```
pushq   %rbp
movq    %rsp, %rbp
subq    $56, %rsp
movl    $0, -32(%rbp)
movl    $0, -28(%rbp)
movl    $0, -24(%rbp)
movl    $0, -20(%rbp)
movl    $0, -16(%rbp)
movq    -32(%rbp), %rax
movq    %rax, (%rsp)
movq    -24(%rbp), %rax
movq    %rax, 8(%rsp)
movl    -16(%rbp), %eax
movl    %eax, 16(%rsp)
call    _Z3foo1S
```

[1] I have removed some lines that I think are unnecessary for the purpose of this question.

Comment: Is there any difference between the two if you compile with `-O3`?

Comment: When you add a destructor, the object has to outlive the call to `foo` to be destroyed. As for the second observation, it seems a conscious decision along the lines of "try to put the arguments into registers while they fit, fall back to stack afterwards".

Comment: @Prætorian With `-O3` the whole call is optimized away in both cases.

Comment: One more thought - once you define any member function, there has to be a way to pass a `this` pointer to it. If your object lives in a register, like your first example, you can't create a pointer to it.

Comment: @DCoder But why can't the object outlive the call in a register like r12 that must not be touched by the callee? I could only think of exceptions and stack unwinding as a potential reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C++03-speak if you define a destructor your struct is not a [POD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plain_old_data_structure)-type anymore. An object of the variant without the destructor behaves like a C struct variable (thus it's just passed around by value), while the one with the user-defined one behaves like a C++ object.

Comment: In your answer you referred to `C++03`; does it mean that the situation is different for the `C++11` standard?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Modification_to_the_definition_of_plain_old_data

Comment: In this particular situation there is no difference, as by C++11 you are turning a trivial class in a non-trivial one by defining a destructor.